# How to correct file extension for thumbnail generation of movie with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I want to upload files and convert thumbnails for it.

My code is:

```
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
module CarrierWave
  module FFMPEG
    module ClassMethods
      def resample(bitrate)
        process :resample => bitrate
      end

      def gen_video_thumb(width, height)
        process :gen_video_thumb => [width, height]
      end
    end

    #def is_video?
    #  ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(File.open(store_path)).frame_rate != nil
    #end

    def gen_video_thumb(width, height)
      directory = File.dirname(current_path)
      tmpfile = File.join(directory, "tmpfile")

      FileUtils.move(current_path, tmpfile)
      file = ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(tmpfile)
      file.transcode(current_path, "-ss 00:00:01 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -s #{width}x#{height}")

      FileUtils.rm(tmpfile)
    end

    def resample(bitrate)
      directory = File.dirname(current_path)
      tmpfile = File.join(directory, "tmpfile")

      File.move(current_path, tmpfile)

      file = ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(tmpfile)
      file.transcode(current_path, :audio_bitrate => bitrate)

      File.delete(tmpfile)
    end
  end
end
```

My Uploader have

```
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 70], :if=> :image?
    process :gen_video_thumb => [100, 70], :if=> :video? do
      process :convert => 'png'
    end
  end
```

and functions are.

```
  protected

  def image?(new_file)
    ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(new_file.file.path).frame_rate == nil
  end

  def video?(new_file)
    ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(new_file.file.path).frame_rate != nil
  end
```

But the problem is that, video is uploaded, video thubmail is generated very good. But it do not have a png extension. If i upload a mp4 file, its thumbnail also have a mp4 extension. but that is an image can be viewed in browser.

How to correct the extension issue? Can any one point out the issue in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently solved this by overriding the `full_filename` method for the `:thumb` version

```
version :thumb do
  # do your processing
  process :whatever

  # redefine the name for this version
  def full_filename(for_file=file)
    super.chomp('mp4') + 'png'
  end
end
```

I called `super` to get the default `:thumb` filename, then changed the extension from `mp4` to `png`, but you could do anything.

For more info, the [carrierwave wiki](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki) has a good article on [How to: Customize your version file names](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Customize-your-version-file-names). Check out the other wiki pages for lots of ideas.